# How do I inject a template into kendo upload's template?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-upload, ng-template

I'm sorry if this has been answered before, but either I'm having a hard time understanding the concept, or I haven't found what I'm looking for. I'm new to templating in Angular (2/4), so please be gracious.

I have a component I've created that implements the kendo upload component. Rather than trying to explain, let me demonstrate what I'd like to do:

```
<attachments [(files)]="model.files">
   <ng-template kendoUploadFileTemplate let-files let-state="state">
     ...
   </ng-template>
</attachments>
```

Inside my attachments component is the kendo upload component:

```
<div class="d-inline-block w-50 p-3">
  <kendo-upload ... [(ngModel)]="files">
    ~~~ I WANT TO INSERT TEMPLATE HERE, IF IT EXISTS ON THE ATTACHMENT COMPONENT ~~~
  </kendo-upload>
</div>
```

Essentially, what I'd like to do is provide the option to use the ng-template at the attachment component level. Otherwise, I want the kendo upload component to use it's internal, default template.

Does that make sense?

I've been trying to use ngTemplateOutlet, but I'm not certain I'm implementing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Replace  "~~~ I WANT TO INSERT TEMPLATE HERE, IF IT EXISTS ON THE ATTACHMENT COMPONENT ~~~" with `<ngContent></ngContent>`. That should work.